# Convert String parameter into res/raw request in helper class, Android

Tags: java, android, resources

I am working on an xslt helper class which I have in my helpers subpackage. I would like to be able to point towards files on disc, in res/raw, or passed in as a string. Because of this, the class receives the xslt info as a string, and I am trying to pass in `R.raw.myfilewithoutextension` as the string to trigger raw lookup.

I attempt to look up the id with:

```
int xsltId = App.get().getResources().getIdentifier(xslt.replace("R.raw.", ""), "raw", App.get().getPackageName());
```

where `App.get()` is a typical helper class that extends Application to give me context. I use this regularly in my helper classes without issues so far.

I am getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources com.mygroup.myproject.App.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I have tried a variety of ways of rewriting the request, but have no clue as to what is wrong here.

The resource definitely exists, and even if I just try to initialize `App.get().getResources()` as a variable, I get the null pointer.

App Class:

```
public class App extends Application {

private static App instance;

public static App get() { return instance; }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: if `App` is subclass of `Application` you have to declare it explicitly in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have used it many, many times...

Comment: Let's try again. Is `App` subclass of `Application` ?

Comment: Could you give more code to let me give any resolution?

Comment: open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add `android:name=".App"` to the `<application` tag

Comment: @Blackbelt, Added to application name in manifest and it is working. Thanks! PS: Did it as follow up before your last response, just letting you know I was listening...